# A single word adjective for "having only one interpretation; leaving no doubts"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, mathematics

I am looking for an adjective with a meaning: 
this is definite, clear, and there's no room for misinterpretation; nothing's left variadic.

For example: logical statements have only one, very strict interpretation. The purpose of the word is similiar: to be used for a mathematical model thoroughly describing a real object. The real object comes in tons of varieties, but the model points to strictly only one.

I've searched the uncle Google and came up with *unequivocal* but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: .... but it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious choice would be [unambiguous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unambiguous), I would say.

Comment: I've used this for an example search in my area of research and - tadam - instant results. Compared to the other answers this did very well.

Answer (score 5):

*unequivocal* sounds right to me.

> [**unequivocal**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unequivocal?show=0&t=1401917151): not subject to misinterpretation or more than one interpretation

As an alternative, consider *irrefutable*.

> [**irrefutable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrefutable): that cannot be refuted or disproved; not able to be proved wrong: not capable of being refuted

Comment: OP says he has done.

Comment: It seems that both `unambiguous` and `unequivocal` are negated versions of other words. I'm wondering if there is a non-negated one as well?

Comment: I first thought of *unequivocal*, meaning something that cannot be argued.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's the problem with this system. We're supposed to furnish answers for people who don't know them, and then submit to their judgment on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

Some general terms include
• *[indisputable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indisputable#Adjective)*, “Not disputable; not open to question; obviously true”
• *[definite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definite#Adjective)*, “Having distinct limits; Free from any doubt; Determined; resolved”

In a mathematical context, consider either of the following terms:
• *[well-defined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well-defined)*, “Accurately and precisely described or specified” and “(mathematics, of a function etc) Defined using unambiguous axioms”
• *[sound](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sound#Adjective)*, “Complete, solid, or secure” and “(mathematics, logic) (argument, logical system) having the [soundness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soundness) property”

Answer (score 2):

[Univocal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Univocal) :

> An expression ,  word or term having only one meaning.

Comment: Can this be used in mathematics/engineering?

Comment: It is used in Statistics  for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The closest to the opposite of lexical ambiguity, or polysemy is **[monosemy](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/87159/monosemous)**: having only one meaning

Answer (score 0):

**Mono-interpretable** would come to mind, which describes a concept of mono-interpretability.

It is the antonym of **poly-interpretable**.

---

To react to the comment below (Shouldn't the antonym of poly-interpretable be poly-uninterpretable? Jokes aside I don't see a one vs many relation as being an antonym.)

*Mono-* is often, if not *always*, used to form the antonym of a word formed with the *poly-* prefix.

A usual antonym for *polygamy* is not *poly-nongamy* or *poly-singleness* or anything describing the idea that someone is multiple times *not married*. The antonym for *married to several people* is *married to one person*: *monogamy*.

Likewise, the antonym for *polytheism* is not *poly-atheism* or any other concept describing the not-believing in several deities, but rather a concept describing a believe in one, as opposed to many, deity: *monotheism*.

One v.s many are perfectly fine antonyms if the one-ness or many-ness are defining properties of the concept. After all, in polygamy, the big point is not that people marry, but that they do it multiple times. Polytheism is not about theism per se, but about the fact there are multiple gods.

Comment: Shouldn't the antonym of **poly-interpretable** be **poly-uninterpretable**?  Jokes aside I don't see a one vs many relation as being an antonym.

Comment: @Oldcat  What about monogamy vs polygamy, or monotheism vs polytheism? I surmise an antonym is anything that inverts the meaning. And if something is poly-uninterpretable one of the two options is then likely mono-interpretable? :)

Comment: *Monogamy and polygamy*, *monotheism and polytheism*, are not pairs of logical opposites. *Atheism*, on the other hand, opposes any form of *theism*. But *agamy* isn't a word: perhaps it should be.

Answer (score 0):

To add an option without negation (*un-* prefix):

In terms of a single meaning of a word or phrase you can use *monosemic* (noun: *monosemy*) with antonym *polysemic* (noun: *polysemy*) as in

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/monosemy